# @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed;

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, pom.xml, binary-compatibility

I am getting below on application startup and it is thrown randomly for different repositories.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: null
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.util.JpaMetamodel.lambda$isSingleIdAttribute$4(JpaMetamodel.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.util.JpaMetamodel$$Lambda$933/342191077.test(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Optional.filter(Optional.java:178)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.util.JpaMetamodel.isSingleIdAttribute(JpaMetamodel.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentPropertyImpl.lambda$new$2(JpaPersistentPropertyImpl.java:111)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentPropertyImpl$$Lambda$922/4723664.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230)
```

Getting this error randomly only on prem servers, in local my application is running fine, Can anyone please help me with this issue as I am stuck since last 2 days?

I;m using spring boot verison : 2.5.0
java version "1.8.0_25"

pom file ::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <!-- Password deobfuscate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.24.v20191120</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>


            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>


            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-json-classic</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JMS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- DB -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.informix/jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.informix</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.6.20151104</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Others -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bull.javamelody</groupId>
            <artifactId>javamelody-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.81.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
       <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-verbose</arg>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>${surefire.jacoco.args}</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                 <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
                 <artifactId>jasypt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>2.0.0</version>
             </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by changing jdk 8 to jdk 11, as the application was configured on spring boot 2.5.0 version. Some of the related dependencies are not backward compatible, hence was getting this issue.